# Can I convert a file to Google Docs if it's already been uploaded?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am writing a program that exports documents from Google Drive into HTML.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.export({
    fileId: file_id,
    mimeType: "text/html"
})
```

But there is a caveat: the MIME type of the given file needs to be `application/vnd.google-apps.document` in order to export correctly.

However, I have many files which are, for some reason, of this MIME type: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

And so my program gives me this error:

> Export only supports Google Docs.

If I [uploaded the files programmatically](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19), I could choose the MIME type. But I am dealing with files that have already been uploaded.

**Is there an API call that lets me convert a file in the Drive from one MIME type to the other?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. My best suggestion would be create a small App Engine app that does the download/upload required, and then expose that as an endpoint. If it (or your JS client) uses the prepared file ID feature, it could return a file ID immediately so the actual delay would be minimal.

Comment: Would that require additional user actions? I want them to be able to click on a link representing their file after authenticating once and immediately see the HTML of a doc.

Comment: No. Your JS client call to the new endpoint would include the Access Token. The new server app will then use that Access Token and will have the same client-id as the JS app. So the user would not need to re-authenticate or re-authorise.